# Force users to download latest version from the app store ios

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to completely remove version 1.1 from the app store and force 1.2 to be the first thing that is installed when a user downloads the app? What happens now is that version 1.1 is installed and asks the user to update to 1.2

Would making 1.2 version 2.1 be a solution?

Comment: Only if you wait (maybe a couple days).  You can't force Apple to sync up all their zillions of iTunes servers instantly.

Answer (score 1):

You can define that version 1.1 is no longer available to download and only 1.2 is, but you cannot force users that have version 1.1 to update to 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

This often happens for a period of time after releasing a new update. Many people report that it is fixed within an hour, yet I have noticed it taking a few days. I have also wondered (but cannot find any evidence for it) if it changes depending on if you have ever installed the app before.

Either way the issue should go away. Just make sure you version 1.1 is no longer available on iTunesConnect. And no, changing the version to 2.1 would not change anything.